# Using If statement in QGIS for automated updating

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql, fields-attributes, if-statement

What I need to do is to get QGIS to calculate values in a category field in an automated fashion out in the field. The statement below just does not work.

```sql
case
    if ("Score_Totl" < '12') then ("Category" = E)  
    if ("Score_Totl" >= '12' and <= '35') then ("Category" = C)  
    if ("Score_Totl" >= '36' and <= '47') then ("Category" = B) 
    if ("Score_Totl" >= '40') then ("Category" = A)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't mix `case when` statements with `if` conditions. If you want to set or change the value of the field `Category`, use field calculator and set output field name to `Category` or use `Update existing field` if this field exists already.

Then the syntax looks like this:

```sql
case 
   when "Score_Totl" < 12 then 'E'
   when "Score_Totl" >= 12 and "Score_Totl" <= 35 then  'C'
   when "Score_Totl" >= 36 and "Score_Totl" <= 47 then 'B'
   when "Score_Totl" >= 40 then 'A'
end
```

---

Be aware:

- For numbers, do not use single quotes `'` - these are for text strings. You can't use `>`, `<` or `=` together with strings.
- No need for brackets in the `when` statements
- If the result (output) should be a string, embrace it in single quotes, thus `'A'`, not `A`
- As mentioned in a comment by user @J.R : You need to repeat the field name (`"Score_Totl"`) after the `and`

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to these inconsistencies, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: To add some more pedantic little improvements: technically, `CASE` statements should be evaluated in sequence, top to bottom. Thus you should be able to omit the lower range check and the `AND` logic